# Having issue in my jquery code. How to apply volume control in this video

Tags: jquery, video

Having issue in my jquery code here is the code: Here is the link  http://lotusvalue.com/ To test my code i have put alert command,when page loads they alert command tells ok, then alert(instance).val(); tells undedefined , I want to achieve the volume control in this video. I am unable to do this, please help me where i did wrong.

```
Html:
<div data-vide-bg="video/real2.mp4" data-vide-options="className: myVideo" class="agile-banner" id='div'>
```

jquery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
alert('ok');
var instance = $('#div').data('vide'); 
var instance = $('.agile-banner').data('vide');
alert(instance);
});
  </script>
```

Comment: For your alert, change it to: alert(instance.val());

Comment: Hi applied not getting alert(instance.val()); and video also stop showing, what code we have use correctly for video volume controls

Comment: Are you testing on Chrome and does the video start automatically?

Comment: yes the video start automatically, how do we set volume controls.

Comment: Chrome has this **[crapy policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)** that severely limits the use of videos that are autoplay. One of the features targeted is volume in that they premit the use of autoplay in mute and you have to have special circumstances in order to autoplay without mute.

Comment: ok but, auto play not a issue  let it be start like that only, but i want to put  drag and drop control and volume control,So how to archive this or else can we do this in html5 , if possible send be me the code, i will try interact in webserver

Comment: All you want is to control volume programmatically?

Comment: yes , If i mouse over  to video, it has to come controls like drag forward and again back ,For ex any youtube channel has

Comment: drag forward what exactly? A range input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the volume for an audio/video tag is `.volume` property--the value is a range of 0 to 1.0:

```
  document.getElementById('vid').volume = '0.5'
```

### Demo

```js
var vid = document.getElementById('vid')
var rng = document.getElementById('rng');
var vol = document.getElementById('vol');

rng.onchange = volCtrl;

function volCtrl(e) {
  var volV = this.value;
  vol.value = volV;
  vid.volume = volV;
}
```

```css
#rng {
  width: 320px
}
```

```html
<video id="vid" width="320" height="240" controls>   
  <source src="https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005612.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video><br>


<input id='rng' type='range' min='0.0' max='1.0' step='0.1' value='0.5'>

<output id='vol'>0.0</output>
```

Comment: hi it is working, now i am facing one problem, if i changing this line  <div data-vide-bg="video/real2.mp4" class="agile-banner"> </div> to<video id="vid" width="320" height="240" controls> </video> the video tags moves to menu part and menu part come down, what to do because the i am unable to figure data-vide-bg="video/real2.mp4", if i remove data-vide-bg this line video is not working

Comment: That is because the  div you see is a placeholder. The actual video tag is generated and then placed about 2 levels deep into that div. Right-click the video and select "inspect". In the dev tools click on that div and open it and then open whatever else is nested within and eventually you'll find the video tag. This video tag doesn't exist until the plugin loads so what you need to do is either generate the controls after video tag is generated or have hardcoded in the DOM beforehand. Is this slider for the user?

Comment: yes this is the slider for user and  also if added only video tag as per your code , it is not suitable for responsive mode, that issue also i am facing now, how to achieve that

Comment: Ok, you can place the slider anywhere you want and give it `position:relative` and `z-index:9999999999`. Then replace this `var vid = document.getElementById('vid')` with this: `var vid = document.querySelector('video');` or `var vid = $('video')[0]` do not use the HTML video tag just the range

Comment: could you please do it and update the code, i applied it is not reflecting, keep the first one as it is and update with new second one answer

Comment: You'll need to ask another question. The layout and implementation of code is too different. My code would be considerably different as well.